# generate Uniq Transaction Id only Number in Laravel6+

Tags: php, laravel, random, uniq, laravel-6.2

I am posting this question here because i could't find the right solution:
I have to make a uniq transaction id which i am generating with the `time()` + `rand()`
In this function still collision can happen.. My question is is there any better way to perform this within (18 digit) , 
And What about the rand(10 digits) vs rand(5)+rand(5)

And is there a way to controll the ramsey uuid() length

Comment: UUIDs are a specific standardised format, so changing their length wouldn't make any sense (the result wouldn't be a UUID any more).

Comment: Currently not released yet (target is Symfony 5.1, which will be soon), would ULID be an option? https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/uid.html#generating-ulids